# Wireless security system for multiple appartments in the EU using the same wi-fi network

Tags: wifi, security

Looking for a security system for a holiday rental business in the EU able to have approx 20 window/door sensors (other security devices such as a siren can also be in the package, but I don t necessarily need a keypad as in-app control is enough) and that sends alerts via app and if possible via email/SMS to multiple people (my self and a local staff member). Ideally No subscription, should be required, except maybe one for the sms.

The holiday apartments are in the same location (radius of approx 30 meters) and are connected on the same WI-FI network (WI-FI signal distributed by multiple antennas).

I don t mind buying multiple systems (of the same brand or not) but I am concerned with the fact that they might not work if connected on the same wi-fi or because a single app can't manage multiple systems of the same brand.

Thanks in advance.